# GIMP: Smooth png image from black to transparent (how to make gradient)?

Tags: gimp, transparency

How to make a transparent 'png' image from black (not transparent) to nothing (absolutely transparent) in GIMP smoothly?

As result, this image on the red image gives the image from black via dark red to red?

This is an example (but not of good quality, I'd like to know how to make this image properly):

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample image of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **gradient**.

Here is a tutorial on [how to make a gradient in Gimp.](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Gradient-in-Gimp)

Here's on [how to  make a custom gradient](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/gimptutorials/ss/Gradient-Editor.htm).

- In your case you would make your gradient as a layer that like you said smooths from black to nothing, this will be your gradient layer.
  The layer under this will simply be filled in red. With  the gradient on top it will make the effect that you want.
- Alternatively you could just have a layer of a custom gradient that goes from black to red.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: There is no need for a custom gradient in this case. One of the built-in gradients is "foreground color to transparency" - all that is  needed is to create a new, transaprent image, and fill it with the belnding tool, unsing the FG to Transparent gradient.

Comment: Exactly :) thank you for clarifying. I thought that it would be beneficial to mention the option to customize.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a layer mask.
(Right click on Layer → Layer Mask → Add alpha channel of the layer)

And then can you use the gradient tool

Here is an tutorial with pictures.

http://infofreund.de/gimp-transparent-gradient/